# Magento 1.6 fails to extract .tgz module

Tags: module, magento-1.6

I created a module in 1.9 and when files are moved across it works fine but when I use the package extension and try to install it from the generated .tgz file it fails.

I've done some debugging and it fails to extract the archive.

```
public function extract($file, $source, $destination='.')
```

This method in `downloader\lib\Mage\Archive.php` does the extraction.

```
$resFile = $this->_getArchiver(self::TAPE_ARCHIVER)->extract($file, $tarFile, $destination);
```

This line extracts it and returns the path to the extracted archive normally but in this case it returns empty.

So in Magento Connect I simply get `CONNECT ERROR: Unsupported resource type` error in the console.

Any idea if maybe Magento 1.6 expects a different type or anything? I've tried repackaging it in the package extension in 1.6 thinking that might help but no joy.

I also checked the `chmod` on the magento directory and all is good.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this first if this work for you:

Navigate to following file `downloader/lib/Mage/Archive/Tar.php`

Replace this 
`const FORMAT_PARSE_HEADER = 'a100name/a8mode/a8uid/a8gid/a12size/a12mtime/a8checksum/a1type/a100symlink/a6magic/a2version/a32uname/a32gname/a8devmajor/a8devminor/a155prefix/a12closer';`

with this

`const FORMAT_PARSE_HEADER = 'Z100name/Z8mode/Z8uid/Z8gid/Z12size/Z12mtime/Z8checksum/Z1type/Z100symlink/Z6magic/Z2version/Z32uname/Z32gname/Z8devmajor/Z8devminor/Z155prefix/Z12closer';`

In php5.5 unzip function has been changed. Hope so this will work for you.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php

if its still not solved then i can look on your package if you send me over `magento@magentoxpert.com` , Also did you try this with some other version `1.7,1.8, or 1.9`? If the error is same then might be your package isn't right.

Comment: You my friend are a life saver!